# How to put wait condition in Signal-Slot?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am doing one web related project. Recently I hit on this situation. This is just a stub

```
Class My_Class
{
public:
    My_Class();
    void start();
public slots():
    void after_Load_Function();
}

My_Class::My_Class()
{
    //Some initializations
    connect(WebPage,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOTS(after_Load_Function()));
}

void My_Class::start()
{
    WebPage->load();
}

void My_Class::after_Load_Function()
{
    //Do something with the finished WebPage
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    //Some Qt things

    My_Class a;
    a.start();
}
```

"WebPage" emits the signal "finished" when it loaded fully.
Now the problem is before the "webPage" got loaded the "start" is returning. Thereby the control reaches the "main". So, now the control should return from "start" only after "after_Load_Function" finishes it's job. Thereby I want the below sequence,

1. main creates the My_Class object A.
2. main calls "start" from A.
3. start calls load from "WebPage" and it waits untill the "WebPage" emits "finished",
     and that emit in turn calls the "after_Load_Function", and "after_Load_Function"
     finishes it's job.
4. now, the "start" returns
5. main returns

But, I don't know how to make this kind of wait condition. How can I go about it?

Comment: What is `WebPage`? If it is based on the Qt Webkit classes, it is very likely that it relies on the event loop to run for it to be able to finish. Blocking on `start` would prevent that, and thus deadlock your application. _Why_ do you want to wait for that event?

Comment: From just skimming this question, it seems to be about certain 3rd party library facilities, i.e. covered by RTFM.

Comment: @Mat the problem is before the "webPage" got loaded, the "start" is returning

Comment: @prabhakaran: I understand what is happening, but not _why that is a problem_. Blocking on the main thread in Qt is usually the wrong thing to do, and can deadlock your application. Why can you not do whatever needs to be done in the slot (or even later)? Does WebPage rely on the event loop?

Comment: @Alf In this project I am using Qt only.

Comment: @Mat The webPage emits a signal after it finished the loading. So there is no way other than siganl-slot.

Comment: @prabhakaran: I understand what the code you posted does. What it does is normal and expected in usual Qt code, which is event/signal-based. **If** WebPage requires the event loop to run, you **cannot** block in start without either deadlocking (i.e. webpage will never load) or doing some things like running the event loop yourself (not recommended). **Why** do you want to wait for that signal? Why is that necessary? What can you not do if control reaches main before the page has finished loading? What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Mat I have to extract images out of that QWebPage once it is loaded. Now the program exits without invoking "after_Load_Function". It is not giving time for WebPage to be loaded.

Comment: That means you're missing the event loop (99% sure). You need to create a `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` and call its `exec()` function after your `a.start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by running a local event loop, letting the components process network income and load the page. When they emit the signal, you execute a slot on the event loop to quit it.

```
void My_Class::start()
{
    QEventLoop qel;
    QObject::connect(WebPage, SIGNAL(finished()), &qel, SLOT(quit()));

    WebPage->load();
    qel.exec();
}
```

I've been using this before and it works fine. I don't advice to use this too often though, because it will process events, including those that the caller of `start` might not be expecting to be processed during the call to `start`, so you *need* to document this to its callers. You can prevent the processing of some events by passing certain flags to `QEventLoop::exec`, like preventing to process user interface events.

Answer (score 0):

You should never wait in UI code.  You need to break your "main" function into pieces so the later part can be executed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use [condition variables](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwaitcondition.html) thats what they are used for. You can make threads wait on a condition variable and proceed when notified.

Comment: Except that you shouldn't be causing the main thread to wait in a UI application.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebPage->load()` method is asynchronous, meaning that it runs immediately, not when the loading is complete. The operation runs in the background while you go to do other things.

This is considered a good thing, as it enables your app to be more responsive and get more done. For example, if your app has a GUI, you could update the GUI with some sort of animation that indicates that the web page is being retrieved.

If you prefer a model in which the application blocks until the page is fully loaded, then consider making this change:

```
void My_Class::start()
{
    WebPage->load();
    while (!WebPage->isLoaded())
        Sleep(1);
    after_Load_Function();
}
```

Notes:

- the `Sleep` function will work on Windows. If you are on a Unix OS you can use `usleep`.
- since this function will effectively block until the web page is loaded, there is no reason to use the signal from the web page object, you can just simply call your handler after the wait completes, as this will make your handler run in the same thread.
- doing this is really bad practice. You may get away with it if your program is command line and has no GUI and/or event loop, but you should consider a better design for your app where the loading of web pages does not block the whole app.